# C# await and sync - am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've ported an app from Android to Windows Phone 7, and was able to use synchronous calls to file io and the like without many problems (I use threads, so this simplifies things).

However, now I'm porting to a Windows 8 Store app, and the XxxAsync() methods are rampant in the api.

Should I just blindly use async apis and hope for the best?

I have various doubts... for example:

Say the user taps the Save button to save the data model. All the saving is done asynchronously. This means the user can go off changing the data model while it is being saved. Won't this mess up the data and corrupt his file if it is modified midway through?

How does this make it easier for the developer?

I've read various async articles (such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx#BKMK_WhentoUseAsynchrony)) but I feel as though I may be missing something...

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You should disable changes to the UI that affect the data being updated.

Comment: As with all async things you need to coordinate access to resources... in your case the data to be saved... you need to make sure that it can't be changed while you are saving it... either by a "readonly-flag" or by first copying the data (in RAM) and savin the copy (which is more user-friendly IMO)...

Comment: tap save button -> disable save button (and navigation, if it might mess up stuff) -> save asynchronously -> on save complete enable save button. easy as pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with async in a UI is that all *your* code runs on one thread (the UI thread). When the user clicks the Save button, your handler runs. At this point, the UI is busy running your code, so the UI is not interactive. When you have prepared a snapshot of the data you want to send to the server, you launch an asynchronous save and (technically speaking) your handler is finished. Control passes back to the UI, which becomes responsive again.

At this point, the user can update the data model, but the OS is not looking at the data model. It's just making sure that a separate buffer of data (the snapshot you created in your Save button handler) is sent to the server. When that has happened, your asynchronous callback is executed - again, on the UI thread. Depending on the version you're using, you may need to transfer that call to the UI thread manually, using [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

This is exactly the same model as used in JavaScript inside the browser.

It doesn't completely solve all synchronisation problems. For example, unless you disable the Save button during the upload, the user can click save again while the server is already receiving the first save. But this is only a problem for the server to worry about, and it better be able to cope with two simultaneous attempted saves.

One possible problem you may have is with your previous versions of the application. If you were using threads all over the place, were you using locks or thread-safe data structures appropriately? The problem you describe definitely exists in a free-threaded application!

Comment: It was hard to choose a correct answer here; thanks for all the replies. Yes of course I knew what I was doing when I was using the thread approach. I wonder how much benefit async constructs are to developers porting apps to windows platforms and why msft I'd forcing them to use APIs... Anyways I was able to get my stuff working nicely, fixing some got has among the way

Answer (score 1):

You should understand **why** and **when** to use async methods, never use them blindly. That goes for almost any programming technique, of course, but it's especially important in the async case since it's easy to potentially mess things up in the future if you don't know what's happening.

**It's important to understand that the async problem you mention isn't different with async/await and using a manual threading solution.** If you don't use async/await (or a manually constructed thread) your UI might feel sluggish or be subject to irritating lock-ups. If you do use it, you have to compensate for the fact that your UI *won't* lock up by disabling input controls, caching the data being saved or what have you.

The async methods scattered around modern APIs shouldn't generally change the way you think about asynchronous or multithreaded code, only how easy it is to apply these ideas to actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have to protect your data, but this is not different than using separate threads. The async pattern lets you create a responsive application without having to use threads explicitely, but it does not solve the problem of access to shared resources. I like the quote from one of the channel9 video's: with responsiveness comes responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just blindly use async apis and hope for the best?

On the Windows Phone platform, you do *have* to use the `async` APIs, but I suggest you do not use them "blindly". Learn about them first; I have an [`async` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that may help.

> Say the user taps the Save button to save the data model. All the saving is done asynchronously. This means the user can go off changing the data model while it is being saved. Won't this mess up the data and corrupt his file if it is modified midway through?

Yes. One common practice is to copy the data and/or disable the controls while the request is outstanding, e.g., this code will copy the data when the save is first requested and also disable the save button until the saving is complete:

```
public async Task SaveAsync(MyData data) { ... }

// Logically, this is an asynchronous ICommand.Execute implementation.
public async void SaveCommand()
{
  saveInProgress = true;
  dirty = false;
  MyData data = CopyData();
  await SaveAsync(data);
  saveInProgress = false;
}

// Logically, this is an ICommand.CanExecute implementation.
public bool CanSave { get { return !saveInProgress && dirty; } }
private bool saveInProgress, dirty;
```

You face the exact same problem when using threads to save.

> How does this make it easier for the developer?

`async` code is much more maintainable than code using threads.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that just because the code executes asynchronously, doesn't mean you have to allow the user to continue to change data as it's being saved.  It does make for a better user experience IMHO because you can decide the method by which the user is prevented from further altering data.

If you save synchronously and it takes a long time (say 30 seconds), the user is faced with a frozen, non-responsive screen for 30 seconds.  Many users will assume at that point that the app has crashed.  However, while this is happening is an asynchronous model, you can simply display a message (and status bar) telling the user what's happening.  Additionally, you have the option to allow them to access other functionality of the app.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just blindly use async apis and hope for the best?

Not, for sure not. Async stuff is very good, to bring to the user the flexible UX, but as you mantion, brings complexity in *management* of your program functional assets in the moment of async stuff execution.

The basic idea, for mobile (and not only) is provide to the user with some `progress` information, and/or `disable` or `hide` from the UI controls (functionality access points) use of which, in that specific moment, can harm user in some way.